# Is there a tool to monitor the SQL statements being executed by an .EXE?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, vb6, monitoring

I'd like to be able to hook into a 3rd party application to see what SQL Statements are being executed.  Specifically, it is a VB6 application running on SQL Server 2005.

For example, when the application fills out a grid, I'd like to be able to see exactly what query produced that data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have the appropriate rights (sysadmin or ALTER TRACE permission) on the DB you could watch using SQL Profiler.

Answer (score 1):

If the application does not write a log or something, the only way to watch them is on the database side. SQL Profiler is the proper tool for the task on MSSQL 2005.

Answer (score 1):

You can view it server side by connecting to the SQL server with the SQL Server Profiler included in the tools.  [Here's a usage run down of it from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing it on the server as other answers indicate is most likely the best way to go.  However, if that's not available, you can also turn on [ODBC logging](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403323(SQL.90).aspx) which may be helpful.